# Saviour I'm ! Silent hero

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Saviour I'm, Saving is my job.

S is crucial, as crucial is my job.

Find me on a bridge, if you want me along

For I sit there, all day long.

What am I?

> Will add a few more lines soon enough as hints.

Hint 1:-

> Saving a pair is what I do the best.

Hint 2:-

> For I come in different shapes and colors.

Comment: Is the bridge of a type - _railway bridge_ ?

Comment: No.. Its just a bridge.. @MeaCulpaNay

Comment: Is it a game of bridge in a deck of cards?

Comment: No @Joe-You-Know

Comment: If I have another answer do I put it in another answer or do I add it into my previous answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be

> Sunglasses

Saviour I'm, Saving is my job.

> Sunglasses keep your eyes safe from the sun

S is crucial, as crucial is my job.

> Here's where I'm not really sure, but wearing sunglasses is crucial if you want to keep your eyes safe.

Find me on a bridge, if you want me along

> You find them on the bridge of your nose

For I sit there, all day long.

> You only need them during the day

What am I?

> Sunglasses

---

hints:
Hint 1

> Saving a pair is what I do the best: They save a pair of eyes.

Hint 2

> For I come in different shapes and colors: Sunglasses come in different shapes and colors

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This is a great first answer! I think you might have nailed it. Only thing I can suggest is maybe adding how the answer fits the hints (which I think it does). Also, feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.

Comment: The correct answer. Well done :)

Comment: nice :) so close ackkk

Answer (score 14):

Could you be a

> Bank?

Saviour I'm, Saving is my job.

> Banks save your money.

S is crucial, as crucial is my job.

> $ looks like an S. Banks are crucial for the economy.

Find me on a bridge, if you want me along

> When you're on a bridge, you can see the river bank.

For I sit there, all day long.

> River banks pretty much just sit there.

Comment: +1 for creativity. Very good answer, but not the answer I had in my mind.

Answer (score 4):

**A bit of a stretch but could you be**

> the sun?

Saviour I'm, Saving is my job.

> The sun literally saves us or we will die.

S is crucial, as crucial is my job.

> S is the start of sun? Here's where the stretch is :P.

Find me on a bridge, if you want me along

> If you look up there, you will see the sun half the time.

For I sit there, all day long.

> You can't find the sun at night.

What am I?

> The sun?

**Second answer is totally wrong, but for reference it's a**

> stop sign

Comment: +1, Very nice and quite near to the correct answer. :)

Comment: Any new clues please?

Comment: Sorry to say but you got completely deviated from the right path.

Comment: Ouch that hurt... I guess I'll delete it?

Comment: Up to You :)...

Answer (score 3):

Are you..

> **A railing?**

Saviour I'm, Saving is my job.

> Railings prevent people from falling off of stuff

S is crucial, as crucial is my job.

> The S at the end of railings is important, because a single railing isn't enough? D:

Find me on a bridge, if you want me along

> Railings are on the sides of bridges to prevent you from falling off

For I sit there, all day long.

> Railings shouldn't move

Comment: Well a good answer but I've never seen a S at the end of any railing ? S really has a crucial meaning way more than being at end of any railing :)

Comment: I think they meant the S is important to make it plural, as a single one isn't enough

Comment: @Mohirl Yes, that is what I intended

Comment: NO.. S is not meant for any ending to a word. It has a typical use in the relation to the answer. Its not their to make things plural.